# BaseAdapter.getCount() throws null pointer exception while the referenced object is absolutely not null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sdk, android-adapter, baseadapter

I'm building both background server and android application for food-ordering project.
There is a function that helps customers make sure whether the table is occupied or not. The logic is written in TableActivity.java which I will show down below. Basically the item to inflate the view is a ImageView and a TextView. ImageView is either vacant or occupied while TextView is the number of the table.
The background code is okay that returns a json string that contains the 
table number and table flag(1 vacant;0 occupied). But the LogCat gave me null pointer exception. I'll be appreciated if you give some advice.

I use tomcat 7 as server software and servlet to handle the connection between client and database. Background is fine and I think the problem is in my android client codes. 
Android SDK version is 27.

```
public class TableActivity extends Activity {
    GridView gv;
    List<Table> list;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.table);
        list = new ArrayList<Table>(); //Table is an Entity class 
        gv = findViewById(R.id.table_gridView);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        //init network
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/WL_Server/TableServlet";
        new MyTask().execute(url);
        gv.setAdapter(myAdapter);


    }

    /*@param: The url of server servlet
     Visit target url, gets the output of the server. The function returns a json that contains info of Tabletbl table.
    * */
    String doGetTableMsg(String url){
        String json = OkHttpUtil.doGet(url);
        return json;
    }


    //异步任务，处理网络请求
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return doGetTableMsg(strings[0]);   
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<Table>>(){}.getType();
            list = gson.fromJson(s, type);  
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            //This return sentence is where the exception happened. But this 
            // list object has been initiated and assigned with value already?
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View view1;
            if (view == null){
                //Inflate a view from an XML resource.
                view1 = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.table_item, null);
            }else {
                view1 = view;
            }


            ImageView imageView1 = view1.findViewById(R.id.itemImageView1);
            TextView textView1 = view1.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView1);

            //Logic to decide whether table is vacant or not. Totally fine.
            Table table = list.get(i);
            int flag = table.getFlag();
            if (flag == 0){
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.kongwei);
            }else {
                imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.youren);
            }
            textView1.setText(table.getTid() + "");
            return view1;
        }
    }

}
```

I expect the emulator will show the view but it gave me null pointer exception like below:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at xuming.com.wl_client.TableActivity$MyAdapter.getCount(TableActivity.java:82)

Line 82 is  `return list.size();`

The normal reason that occurs this could be using [findViewById] instead of [View.findViewById] in getItem method but I've already used the latter one.
Appreciated and if you need more codes I'll provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should place your    `gv.setAdapter(myAdapter);` within `onPostExecute()`

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Table>>(){}.getType();
        list = gson.fromJson(s, type);  
        gv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and also change your `getItem()` and `getItemId()`to :

```
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return list.get(i).getId;
    }
```

Comment: yeah that's the issue. Thanks and still thinking about the reason.

Comment: you are welcome , the reason is you are setting adapter with an empty list , so you should wait until your list get values .please mark it as correct and vote it if it was helpful , thanks :)

Comment: Yeah..but sorry mate system says I can only mark it as long as my reputation gets 15...And mine is 1. :( Still appreciated. I'll mark it as correct when I get enough reputation.

Comment: Okei , i will appreciate it

Comment: I think you can mark it as correct now , so please don't forget it , and thanks !

Comment: Already marked as correct. Thanks for help and I got another problem in my question list would you mind kindly check it out?

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.table);
    list = new ArrayList<Table>(); //Table is an Entity class 
    gv = findViewById(R.id.table_gridView);

    //myAdapter = new MyAdapter(); //remove; intialize after web request has a value

    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/WL_Server/TableServlet";
    new MyTask().execute(url);
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    ...
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Table>>(){}.getType();
        list = gson.fromJson(s, type);  //debug here, maybe gson is returning null

        //inizialize adapter whit list
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(list);
        gv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        List<Table> adptList;

        public MyAdapter(List<Table> list){
            this.adptList = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.adptList.size();
        }
        ...
        ...
        ...
}
```

Place your `setAdpetr()` after `AsyncTask` finish execution, and add constructor for your adapter.

Comment: The gson was returning null after debugging. Thanks and appreciated!